# radio buttons to choose workflow

Tags: javascript, html

Sort of long, but I'm hoping someone might be able to help! I'm working on a program to be used for tuning purposes in music composition and there are basically two workflows: 1) string of button inputs, and 2) direct numerical ratio input. From the get-go, I have 2 radio buttons to choose which method the user would like to use. Basically, there is only a difference in a var I've called "inputs": in workflow 1) it's the sum of a number of arrays (based on button click); in workflow 2) it's based on the numerator and denominator given by the user. All the parts work individually, but don't work when I combine them together in the following.

So my two radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="inputType" id="noteInput">Note Input
<input type="radio" name="inputType" id="ratioInput">Ratio Input
```

and the important place in the script:

```
function getInputSum(){
    if ( $("#noteInput").checked ){ 
        inputSum = reference
        .SumArray(refOctave[getRefOctave()]) 
        .SumArray(refNote[getRefNote()]) 
        .SumArray(refAccidental[getRefAccidental()])
        .SumArray(autoOffsetToA)
        .SumArray(notes[getNote()])
        .SumArray(chromatic[getChromatic()])
        .SumArray(octave[getOctave()]) 
        .SumArray(syntonic[getSyntonic()])
        .SumArray(septimal[getSeptimal()])
        .SumArray(undecimal[getUndecimal()])
        .SumArray(tridecimal[getTridecimal()])
        .SumArray(seventeen[getSeventeen()])
        .SumArray(nineteen[getNineteen()])
        .SumArray(twentyThree[getTwentyThree()])
        .SumArray(twentyNine[getTwentyNine()])
        .SumArray(thirtyOne[getThirtyOne()]);
    } else if ( $("#ratioInput").checked ){
        smallestTerms = reduce(inputNum,inputDen);
        $("#num").text(smallestTerms[0]);
        $("#den").text(smallestTerms[1]); 

        numArray = getArray(smallestTerms[0]);
        denArray = getArray(smallestTerms[1]);

        inputSum = reference
        .SumArray(refOctave[getRefOctave()]) 
        .SumArray(refNote[getRefNote()]) 
        .SumArray(refAccidental[getRefAccidental()])
        .SumArray(numArray)
        .DiffArray(denArray);
       }
}
```

Of course, I've left out a number of functions that are being called, but as I said, it seems to only not work if I combine them as I have. And if I remove the if else if leaving only the inputSum calculation in the if part, the rest of the program works fine, etc.

Wondering if it's something simple in the above that I'm missing?

Using JQuery.

Comment: Try using `$("#noteInput").prop("checked")` instead

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `$("#noteInput").checked`
The jQuery object has no property checked.
It is the underlying DOM element that has it.
You can use `.prop()` to access it.

```
$("#noteInput").prop('checked')
```